# Unable to send HTTP request in Safari Mobile

Tags: java, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I'm new here. So, let me introduce myself first. My Name is David Budiman as shown by my Screen Name.

I have came across this forum, because I'm having a problem with my web app in Safari Mobile in iOS 7 or lower.

See, the problem is that my website works perfectly in every other device or OS. But, in Safari Mobile in iOS 7 or lower, it seems to not work at all. The link to my website would direct me to the website just as expected, but any other actions I performed on the website won't get any response from the server. Such as clicking the "Login" Button.

I developed my website using Java 1.6 on Windows.

The link to my website is: https://klikpay.klikbca.com/

I have searched through the site and found nothing to help me.

I'm hoping that perhaps someone here might have the answer to my question. Thank you very much.

Any screenshot needed, I would be happy to provide.

Comment: What happens in Mobile Safari when you go directly to https://klikpay.klikbca.com/login.do?action=validateLogin ?

Comment: Could you perhaps show some code so we get a better idea of what could be the case? Only if it's a well known problem we could know this out of the blue probably.

Comment: @Drakes, I never really tried that. I'll give that a try in a minute.

Comment: @Joop, I don't think the problem is with the code, since in iOS 8, the site works perfectly. The only known problems with my clients are when they use iOS 7 or lower. I have looked into Wireshark and saw a high number of TCP reset (doesn't happen with other browsers) from the client side when posting HTTP request

Comment: @Drakes, I have tried it... And it works just like a normal link should. The response I got from the server was correct and there was no delay.